# Changing the Colour of Specific Characters in a Cycling Randomized String

Tags: c#, console-application

Using a C# console application.

The code is intended to cycle randomly through letters to try and find a password. When a letter matches a letter in the password, it will stay, until all letters match.

For now, I am using "ALGORITHM" as a placeholder.

By default, letters are red.

However, I want the specific characters to change their (and only their) foreground colour to green when they are matched. Colours not yet matched should stay red.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {

        // let's figure out how to make specific letters a specific colour.
        // if not letter, RED. if letter, CYAN.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            List<string> dictionary = new List<string>(new string[] {
            "ALGORITHM"
        });

            string word = dictionary[r.Next(dictionary.Count)];
            List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(letters[r.Next(letters.Length)]);
                if (sb[i] != word[i])
                {
                    indexes.Add(i);

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            while (indexes.Count > 0)
            {
                int index;

                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.Clear();

                for (int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    index = indexes[i];
                    sb[index] = letters[r.Next(letters.Length)];
                    if (sb[index] == word[index])
                    {

                        indexes.RemoveAt(i);




                    }


                }
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());



            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing all the characters all at once using `Console.WriteLine`, set the foreground color of the console, write one character with `Console.Write`, change the color, write another character, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write characters in different colors, you need to change the color before writing each character. In your case for instance, you could replace the last `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());` by:

```
var output = sb.ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
{
    if (indexes.Contains(i))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }

    Console.Write(output[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine();
```